# Coin Toss Combination Probability With Some Combinations Excluded

Tags: probability

If a player tosses a coin twice, the probability of getting 2 heads is `0.25`, since there are 4 possible combinations: `HH`, `HT`, `TH`, and `TT`. The game can represented in the form of a binary tree.

[image: 24]

If the rule is changed and the game is over if the player gets the tail after the 1<sup>st</sup> toss, what is the probability of getting 2 heads? Is it `1/3` (since there are only 3 combinations possible: `HH`, `HT`, and `T`)?

[image: 22]

Comment: No.  The probability of something happening is **not** simply going to be the number of outcomes divided by the total number of outcomes.  You can only do that if you know ahead of time that the outcomes are equally likely.  $T$ will have probability $0.5$ and $HT$ and $HH$ will each have probability $0.25$.  The outcomes are not equally likely.

Comment: There are two outcomes to playing the lottery, you win or you lose.  You do not win with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: You cannot split the $0.5$ under the left H into $0.33+0.33$ on the right

Comment: The only situation in which the probability of getting two heads is affected is when you allow three throws and then count how many heads you had. Then stopping early on the first tail prohibits you from throwing two consecutive heads.

Comment: @JMoravitz, thank you for your comment! It is interesting that impossible combinations still influence the probability of the outcome. How is it called? Is it a conditional probability?

BTW, if you could post your comment as an answer, I'd gladly accept it as a solution.

Comment: @Henry, thank you for your comment! Now I see that if we are to continue the game, the probability of win will be divided by 2 with each new toss.